# Android Image Button

Tags: android, imagebutton

I Have scoured the site and several others and I am having a problem finding a way to make a clarity nice icon styled image button.  The image buttons I keep using fill the content and look just distorted, I want very nice looking icons styled image buttons, and instead its smudged stamps with little clarity.  I want them spaced enough you can see the background behind them, Do i need to somehow make the src the image and the background clear?

heres some of my code:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/debface"
        >


        <TableLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="bottom"
         >


       <!-- Images coming out Blurry, I need to compress like a hires icon file -->
       <TableRow>
       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/debraidcard"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="25px"
        android:paddingLeft="25px"
          android:paddingRight="25px"
        />  
       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/debraidcard"
        android:padding="25px"
        android:paddingLeft="25px"
        android:paddingRight="25px"
         />
      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/debraidcard"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="25px"
        android:paddingLeft="25px"
        android:paddingRight="25px"
         />
       </TableRow>
```

I have used several different sizes on my images, i have switched between .jpg and .png.  I follwed several tutorials, didn't like the outcomes.  Any help pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of setting your image to the background set it to src:

`android:src="@drawable/cool_drawable"`

that will give you your bitmap in the center of what looks like the default button.
If you don't like the button in the back set the background to `#00000000 (transparent)` and you will end up with only your `Drawable` as the button.

Comment: Now even though it compiles and looks like i want it too it has become force closing constantly.  This was only a single change of the few i made, any ideas

Comment: the error was that i was still using buttons in the java code and not Image buttons